# make4ht and hyphens and apostrophes

Tags: html, htlatex, make4ht

make4ht incorrectly outputs en-dash, em-dash and apostrophes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
-- --- '
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `make4ht test.tex` outputs garbage `â€“ â€” â€™`. Note that `htlatex test.tex` gives the correct output (`&#8211; &#8212; &#8217;` in html). But I want to also use `mathjax`, which means I need to use `make4ht`, right? I am using Windows PowerShell if it makes a difference. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I get the correct utf8 chars `– — ’`. Perhaps your editor is opening the file in some 8bit encoding?

Comment: The characters are not garbage, they are dashes in UTF-8 but you are reading them with a legacy 8bit encoding

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My browser displays the output html file as â€“ â€” â€™. How do I fix that?

Comment: Which browser you used? It's better to use `Google Chrome` or the latest version of `Mozila`

Comment: I have tried several different browsers, and they all display ``â€“ â€” â€™``. The issue is with the html file generated by make4ht, which includes the line ``<p class='noindent'>â€“ â€” â€™ </p>``.

Comment: Can you post the HTML file here? It seems like it contains a wrong declaration of the file encoding. Whad TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: Here is the html output by make4ht 
``<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='iso-8859-1' /> 
<meta name='generator' content='TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)' /> 
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' /> 
<link type='text/css' href='test.css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
<meta name='src' content='test.tex' /> 
</head><body>
<!-- l. 5 --><p class='noindent'>â€“ â€” â€™ </p> 
</body> 
</html>``

Comment: And I use ``texlive 2019``.

Comment: `make4ht -u test` fixes this problem